# Using natbib on LyX

Tags: lyx, natbib, miktex2.9

I have a LyX (version 2.2.3) project that uses a .bib file (created using JabRef), in my project I can make citations of all the files included in my .bib file, but when I try to make a PDF preview the citations appear as ?, and when I try to compile the master file it gives these errors on each citation:

> Undefined control sequence
>
> Argument of \@citex has an extra }
>
> Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete
>
> Paragraph ended before \NAT@split was complete

I've tried to install manually the natbib package and reconfiguring LyX, but it keeps giving the same error, as if it can't find the natbib package. I've also tried to manually force the inclusion by adding this line in the preamble:

`\usepackage{natbib}`

If someone can please shed some light for me on this, I really don't know what I can do anymore, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use cite package? If yes... try to remove it and test it again... (natbib combined with cite package causes such problems... try to use only one of them -I have no idea on how to do it on lyx-)

Comment: The cite package was indeed installed, I removed it and reconfigured LyX, but I get the same errors still. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you remove natbib and use just simple bibliography (I thing numerical or something like this is another option...) Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Doing in the numerical way I get the same error, but the referer is: $T=\sum T_{i}$ \citet

Comment: Can you place the cite comand inside `{}` and check again with both ways? I found something like this earlier. I don't know if can be done in lyx. But if it can be done test it

Comment: Actually my bad, in the numeric way It worked, and strange that the references appeared as: (Author Name, Year) in the PDF file. Tried using with {} with natbib and it did'nt solve the problem, but it's fine and working in the numeric way, thank you! Please awnser the question with the anwser you gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not really found a way to solve the problem with natbib, but numerical way worked fine for the OP's needs.

Failed:
We tried to include the `\cite` command in `{}` but didn't worked.

Didn't try:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/home/my_user/test_bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

in preamble.

If someone has the same problem and find other solution, please post it!

Comment: I understand that we actually didn't solve the natbib problem in LyX, but you solved my problem, so I think is enought to accept the anwser. If anyone else knows how to solve this, post an anwser please!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by setting the **Language Encoding** from `Unicode(ucs-extended)(utf8x)` to `Unicode(utf8)`.

My error probably occurred due to a very fancy name (Žliobaitė).

You can find this option in:

```
Document -> Settings... -> Language -> Encoding - Other
```

LyX Version 2.2.4 on Linux